# Trouble stopping Tomcat due to apparent threading issue

Tags: multithreading, spring, tomcat

With our Java webapp running on Apache Tomcat 6.0.18 on Ubuntu with Java 1.6.0_6, we can stop tomcat just fine.

However, with the same war file deployed to a Apache Tomcat 6.0.18 on Red Hat Enterprise Linux with Java 1.6.0_13, calling `/etc/init.d/tomcat6 stop` does not stop Tomcat.  I have not yet attempted using 1.6.0_6 on Red Hat to see what happens.  Until I get there, any ideas?

jstack shows No deadlocks.  The webapp is using Spring 2.5.6 and JAX-WS to expose SOAP-based web services, in case that matters.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are the CATALINA_HOME and JAVA_HOME variables set on the RHEL machine?

Comment: Yes, both are set.  Identical heap size, max perm size, etc.  Both are now using jdk1.6.0_13 32-bit.  Notice tomcat 6.0.18 on RH spawns one process (one PID), whereas tomcat 6.0.18 on Ubuntu starts three PIDs.  Still investigating -- no root cause yet.

Comment: What is in catalina.out?